Getting 404 Error with Mailchimp Webhook URL in API Gateway
Description:
I'm setting up a webhook in Mailchimp to trigger events in my AWS Lambda function via AWS API Gateway. When I enter the API Gateway endpoint URL as the callback URL in Mailchimp's webhook setup, I consistently get a 404 error.
From Mailchimp's documentation, I understand that the webhook sends data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Current Setup:
API Gateway Integration:
Integration Type: Lambda Function
HTTP Method: POST
Request:
Can someone help me understand what might be causing the 404 error when Mailchimp attempts to verify my webhook URL? Are there specific configurations in API Gateway that I should check to ensure compatibility with application/x-www-form-urlencoded data from Mailchimp?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Reference docs: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/sync-audience-data-webhooks/

What is the URL you are using?

thanks for the response. url: https://tuvdfbvy3i.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/subscribe

And you provided the https:// prefix when you entered this?

yes that is correct. i know requests make it through the gateway and trigger the lambda if i modify the lambda to accept json and hit it via postman, but 404 no matter what when trying via the webhook. thats why im thinking it must be a gateway config issue, but no logs on cloudwatch due to the 404

aws gateway invoke url: https://tuvdfbvy3i.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/subscribe
